# Should Solidity handle the Paging in a Dapp?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm using a smart contract to store a dynamic array that can grow in length. I want to render this list in the browser and would normally do that using web3 and sending a call() to get the list from the blockchain. But, since the array could potentially contain thousands of elements I wouldn't want to do this due to high gas price.

Is it appropriate to implement paging of data within the Solidity contract? If not, what other options are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *since the array could potentially contain thousands of elements I wouldn't want to do this due to high gas price*

The [.call()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) web3 method invokes the [eth_call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) RPC method, which is gas free.

It can't change the contract state (update storage, emit events, ...) but it shouldn't matter in your use case, if you're only reading the data. It's recommended to use the `call()` method only in combination with Solidity functions that are marked with the `view` or `pure` [state mutability](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html#state-mutability) modifiers.